# zlib.output_compression doesn't work when Content-Length is set

Tags: php, http-compression

I have trouble compressing PHP output when the Content-Length header is set. Following [this very similar question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53314451/apache-output-compression-doesnt-work-when-content-length-is-set), it seems I've narrowed down the issue, which happens even without defining output compression in Apache's `.htaccess`.

So I'm using Apache 2.4.18, .htaccess is empty, `AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml` is commented out in Apache configuration, because I want the compression to happen in PHP.

My minimal PHP code:

```
<?php

ini_set("zlib.output_compression", "On");

$output = "";

for ($i = 0; $i < 4000; $i++) {
    $output .= "Foobar ";
}

// header("Content-Length: " . strlen($output));
header("Content-Type: text/html");

echo $output;

exit;
```

It works fine as is, the output is compressed (it's not the case if I omit the `ini_set` call, as expected).

Now if I uncomment the `Content-Length` header line, suddenly the output is not compressed anymore.

**EDIT:** In my case, the problem is solved, see my comments below.

Comment: [Self-answer as a comment, because it's not really an answer] I suspect this behaviour is deliberate, as it happens on the Apache side too (see my other question, linked in this one), and considering the Content-length header is supposed to indicate the *compressed* size, not the uncompressed size as is the case here.

Comment: Try keeping it commented out and see if the handler adds the length of compressed content.

Comment: The reason I started experiencing this issue is because I switched to Slim using PHP-DI's Slim-Bridge (https://github.com/PHP-DI/Slim-Bridge), and the default configuration sets the `addContentLengthHeader` to `true`, forcing Slim to add the Content-Length header to the uncompressed content before handing it to Apache. The fix was as simple as adding `"settings.addContentLengthHeader" => false` in my definitions array.

Comment: @SalmanA The line commented out, there's no Content-Length header added by anyone in the end (but the content is compressed).